# Two caption names for figures

Tags: graphics, floats, labels

I am typing my thesis in LaTeX and I have problems with captions.
In my thesis are pictures as well as graphs. According to my school I have to have these captions:
picture: "`Obr. XXX`",
graph: "`Graf. XXX`".

I use Czech babel.

Pictures are displayed correctly, but how can I change this caption when I include graph as a picture?
I have tried `\newcommand` as well as `\renewcommand` but with these commands I have changed all captions from pictures to graphs.

**Edit:**
example of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, hidelinks]{report}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
...

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{figure}
\caption{This is figure. Caption should be "Obr. 1 This is figure."}
\label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{graph}
\caption{This is graph. Caption should be "Graf. 1 This is graph."}
\label{fig:graph}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I suspect some solution with the `caption` package, however.

Comment: I've added MWE as well as corrected my anwer. In my real document I have loaded many packages as well as some settings but I hope, you will see from MWE where is my problem.

Comment: Must graphs and pictures be numbered independently?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, they must.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`newfloat`](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/newfloat.pdf) package to create a floating environment `graph` for graphs.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, hidelinks]{report}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mwe} % for 'example-image'
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{graph}
\addto\captionsczech{%
  \renewcommand{\graphname}{Graf.}%
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{Obr.}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
\caption{This is figure. Caption should be "Obr. 1 This is figure."}
\label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{graph}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
\caption{This is graph. Caption should be "Graf. 1 This is graph."}
\label{fig:graph}
\end{graph}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: This is great and elegant solution. I've never heard about newfloat package... It works perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: How would one do the same thing, but for tables? For example, I want to have one table caption be "Supp. Table" and another "Comp. Table".