# Two caption names for tables

Tags: tables, floats, captions

I want to create two distinct caption names for tables. In essence, I want to do the same as in this post ([Two caption names for figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237189/two-caption-names-for-figures/237203#237203)), but for tables instead of figures. I tried using the `\usepackage{caption}` environment and modifying it, but it has not worked for me.

Comment: Can you describe what did not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{diag}[Diagram][Table of diagrams]
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
TABLE
\caption{Title}
\end{table}

\begin{diag}[t]
\centering
DIAGRAM
\caption{Title}
\end{diag}
\end{document}
```